# warning: integer constant is too large for "long" type

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

I have the following code.

```
  uint32_t reg_val = 0;
  uint64_t val = 0;
  reg_val = 0;
  reg_val = ((val & 0xffffff000000) >> 24);
  dev_write(rw,reg_val);
```

The compiler gives a warning that says

```
warning: integer constant is too large for "long" type
```

I am only assigning 24 bits to reg_val which is define to be unsigned integer of size 32bits.

Why is the compiler generating this warning?

Comment: What's the intended purpose of masking-off the lower 24 bits, right before right-shifting the value such that the lower 24 bits are removed? It appears to me as redundant code with no real purpose.

Comment: It avoid having anything in the *upper* bits, I imagine.

Comment: I'm vaguely recalling that you need to append "LL" to the literal to make the compiler happy.

Comment: @greggo - wouldn't that only be useful if we were doing a rotate-right, rather than a shift-right? I.e in a situation where the LSB was inserted as the MSB, rather than discarded, as is the case with a shift-right/shift-left.

Comment: @enhzflep Well, it could also be `(val & 0xFFFFFFffffffULL)>>24`, or `(val>>24) &0xFFFFFF`, but when using the first form, it's common to use zeros for the mask in bits discarded by the shift, just to make it clear which bits will remain. What I meant by 'upper bits', is that you can't simplify to (val>>24) since that retains bits 55:24 of the uint64 rather than the desired 47:24 - so the masking operation itself is not redundant, just some of its effect ... I may have misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 8):

The constant `0xffffff000000` is too large for a 32-bit long, which ranges to `0x7fffffff` in your case.

Write it as `0xFFFFFF000000ULL` (`unsigned long long`)
or avoid the issue by writing

```
reg_val = (val >> 24) & 0xFFFFFF;
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on greggo's fine answer a bit.

How an integer literal is defined depends on which version of language we are in.

In C99, integer literals automatically have a type which can contain their value (unless no such type exists). So, assuming 32-bit `long`, then this constant would already have type `unsigned long long`, so no warning should occur.

I don't have a copy of the C89 text, but C89 does not have `long long`. If the rules are similar, then what would happen would be that the constant is converted to 32-bit `unsigned long` in an implementation-defined manner (probably, truncating higher bits).

Since the OP got a warning, but is also able to solve it with the `ull` suffix, it suggests that he is using compiler extensions. In theory, if a compiler offers `long long` in a C89-like mode, then it *should* also update its integer literal rules, so that a literal that cannot fit in `long` has type `long long` (possibly unsigned).

However, I have heard that compilers exist that don't do this; they truncate the literal instead of giving it a type that fits, unless you put the suffix on yourself.

**tl;dr** - suffix shouldn't be necessary; but it never hurts to use it, and it can work around badly-implemented compiler extensions.

Comment: Or they'll promote to the type which fits, but grump about it with a warning, which is good to have in case you ever move the code to one of those 'other' compilers. One issue with this whole 'auto type' approach : if you have e.g. 0xFFFF0000, it can make a big difference to the result according to whether it's done as uint32 or as int64.

Comment: Suppose my expression is `(intvar1 + Literal_Const)*intvar2 >> 8`, and Literal_const is either 0x7FFF8000, or 0xFFFF0000, or 0x1FFFE0000; so is taken as int32, uint32, or int64. That's a pretty bumpy road. Explicit types are essential in this case.

Comment: 0xFFFF0000 must be unsigned according to C99  (and I think also for C89 , AFAIK rules were not changed for types other than `long long` between these two versions) - the smaller-width type is always preferred to the larger-width type, fur hex and octal constants (but not for decimal constants!)

Comment: In that example a wise option would be to make `intvar1` be `ull`, which would cause the other to be promoted whatever type it is; and since hex literals are always positive values there is no issue with sign extension or anything. (Not saying you shouldn't put the suffix on either, of course).

Comment: The 'bumpy road' I was referring to, is that I might have expected  the `>>` to be done with sign extend, which won't happen if Literal_Const is taken as unsigned... but will if it's taken as an int. So, a possibly unexpected dependency  on the value of a constant. making `intvar1` `ull` would indeed ensure that it's handled consistently. Since running into a few of these gotchas I tend to use more apparently-redundant casts than I used to.